# Выводиться не то что нужно, что не так?

Tags: python

Пишу программу парсинга сайтов, но написал только одну функцию, но она работает не так как я хотел.
Мой код:

```
from math import ceil as n

site = 0

genre = str(input('1.сайт1 2.сайт2 \n Напишите цифру сайта:  '))

q = int(input('Какое количество материала вы хотите получить?: '))
# делим на 30 потому что на сайте 30 материалов, потом округляя мы узнаём сколько страниц нам нужно
q /= 30
q = n(q)
print(q)

if genre == 1:
    site = f'сайт1.ру/?с={q}'
if genre == 2:
    site = f'сайт2.ру/?с={q}'


print(site)
```

в идеале на данные:

```
1.сайт1 2.сайт2 
 Напишите цифру сайта:  1
Какое количество материала вы хотите получить?: 60
```

программа должна ответить этим:

```
сайт1.ру/?с=2
```

но она отвечает этим:

```
2
0
```

Почему так происходит я не знаю

Comment: Вы сравниваете строку с числом, получаете всегда `False`. Попробуйте сравнивать со строкой: `genre == "1"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`input` выдаёт вам строку и вы сравниваете его с числом

```
genre = str(input('1.сайт1 2.сайт2 \n Напишите цифру сайта:  '))
```

замените на

```
genre = int(input('1.сайт1 2.сайт2 \n Напишите цифру сайта:  '))
```

Comment: Спасибо большое

Answer (score 1):

Двойку выводит print(q), а в if вхождений нет т.к. при вводе вы конвертируете str в str, а потом сравниваете с int:

```
genre = str(input('1.сайт1 2.сайт2 \n Напишите цифру сайта:  '))  # str
if genre == 1:  # str == int
```

По сути надо конвертировать в int:

```
genre = int(input('1.сайт1 2.сайт2 \n Напишите цифру сайта:  '))
```

и убрать вывод q

Comment: Спасибо, тупанул